# Weird mime-type overwrite issue when serving static files from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mime-types

I am using NodeJS to serve files from my views directory (no express). I am following an app, server, router, handler structure with handler possessing almost all the code.

Here is the code for handler.js:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
formidable = require('formidable');

function handle(pathname, method, viewDir, response){
    let filePath;
    console.log(pathname);
    if(pathname==='/'){
        pathname = '/main.html';
    }

    if(pathname==='/favicon.ico'){
        debugger;
        response.end();
    }
    else{
        filePath = viewDir + pathname;
        //fileext = pathname.substr(pathname.lastIndexOf('.')+1);   
        fileExt = path.extname(pathname);
        console.log(filePath+'\n'+fileExt);
        if(fileExt!==''){
            fs.readFile(filePath, function(err,data){
                if(err){
                    response.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    response.end('<h1>Error reading file!</h1>');
                }
                if(data){
                    debugger;
                    // console.log({'Content-Type': 'text/' + fileExt.substr(1)=='js'?'javascript':fileExt.substr(1)});
                    let mimeType = 'text/' + (fileExt.substr(1)=='js'?'javascript':fileExt.substr(1));
                    console.log(mimeType);
                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeType});
                    response.write(data);
                    response.end();
                }
            });
        }   
        else if(pathname==='/upload' && method.toLowerCase()==='post'){
            //some formidable code here
            response.end();
        }
        else{
            response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.end('<h1>404 File not found!</h1>');
        }
    }

}

    exports.handle = handle;
```

And this is main.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Caption generator for images</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css"></link>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Caption generator for images</h1>
        <h3>Generates a list of captions appropriate for your uploaded picture by visual recognition.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Upload image</h1>
        </div>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageInputFile">Image input</label>
                <input id="image-input-file" type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image-input-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" accept="image/*">
                <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Upload an image file or use already uploaded image.</small>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="file_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if I remove the last script tag from main.html everything loads fine but if its present my main.css file gets served with mime-type text/javascript.

What am I not seeing?

I also see two text/javascript getting logged and both of them are after main.js gets served. If I cut and paste the link tag for my main.css after my script tag both of them get served as text/css.

Does this have something to do with my fileExt being a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to declare variable fileExt. My bad!

```
let fileExt;
```

Inserting the above statement after declaring pathname variable or anywhere before "fileExt" is first used solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a confusion between the paths between ServerSide and ClientSide.
In your HTML the css is with ./main.css but for the JS your using directly main.js

I don't have the full project to check the folders / URL that are being loaded.

Is there a reason to not use ExpressJS? 
for example if your directories are like:

```
app/
app/index.js
app/public/{here your css, main}
```

And in index.js
You just have to

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Comment: It's only for learning purpose that I am going vanillla as much as possible here. 
As for the urls they seem alright and I could see the files in sources tab under chrome. All static files are present in one directory named views.